# How to fit child div to parent div when parent div have padding?

Tags: html, css

I've inserted an `<input type=text />` to the `.searchbox` div, but it's overflowing out of the body from the right because of the padding. How can I fix this?

```
.searchbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    background-color:#0099FF;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.inputb {
    width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 490px) {
   .searchbox {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <input class="inputb" type="text" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan34/yLH7L/4/

Comment: no, that is my problem

Comment: Then it's unclear what's the problem with it

Comment: @itay Clear enough "but it's overflow from right by have scrolling"

Comment: @bjb568 What language is this?

Comment: @Itay gibberish maybe? or dunken master...

Comment: @Itay Come on, it's not that hard.

Comment: @Itay .searchbox is overflowing out of body?

Comment: btw this is not a javascript question is only CSS related

Comment: yes, its overflow out from the body and have scrolling in horizontal.

Answer (score 3):

Add box-sizing: border-box. It makes width be computed for the border-box, instead of the content-box. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLH7L/7/). It's support is [good enough](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing), and forcing old browsers into quirks mode will make all elements render as border-box. (It's a good idea to give old browsers very minimal CSS, anyway. If you do that, quirks mode shouldn't break much)

```
.searchbox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    background-color:#0099FF;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `calc` function in css. chek this http://jsfiddle.net/yLH7L/6/

Comment: updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLH7L/6/) to work with the 490px media size... just because i was bored

Comment: @VladimirRosca you forgot the width, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLH7L/8/) am I bored too? :D

Comment: @Adrian Enriquez Funny story. The ONLY eidt  i made was to add the width but it would seem i copied the wrong URL... so my comment is useless. my fiddle _was_ going to look exactly like yours

Comment: @Arjun also +1 for teaching me about the calc function. didn't even know that was a thing. thanks

Comment: that is because default padding of textbox so you have to remove default padding of textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your code and ready only works in recent browsers is css3

```
 .searchbox {
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px; 
            background-color:#0099FF;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            box-sizing:border-box; --- take look a this
        }
```

if you need full cross browser solution take a look at [CSS Div width percentage and padding without breaking layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538875/css-div-width-percentage-and-padding-without-breaking-layout)

complete explanation of `box-sizing` http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brendan34/yLH7L/4/). It uses percentage sizes.

```
.searchbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    background-color:#0099FF;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
.inputb {
    width: 98%;
 }
@media (max-width: 490px) {
    .searchbox {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yLH7L/9/)

```
.searchbox {
    width: 96%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#0099FF;
    padding: 0 2%;
}
.inputb {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
@media (max-width: 490px) {
    .searchbox {
        width:94%;
        padding-left: 3%;
        padding-right:3%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use a `<div>` with negative margins

For any child element, the maximum natural width cannot exceed that of the parent's content width — even if the parent has `box-sizing: border-box` defined.

On typical block-level elements and most elements defined with `display: block`, you can stretch the child by giving it negative margins equivalent to the padding of the parent container.

This only works if the element has no defined width or it has `width: auto` explicitly defined. Defining `width: 100%` is insufficient.

For some reason there is no way to accomplish this directly on an `input` even if you have defined `display: block` (this applies to `textarea` and possibly other form elements as well).

I suspect this is because `width: auto` defers to the element's default browser-defined width which is calculated uniquely for `input` elements.

You can, however nest the `input` within a container that has no padding of its own to which you've also applied the negative margins.

Consider the following examples:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } /* FTW */
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
.myuncoolparentdiv {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color:#0099FF;
}
.mycoolparentdiv {
    margin: 0 -20px;
}
.mybadinputtoo {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 -20px;
}
.myreluctantinput {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.mycoolinput {
    width: 100%;
}
.mycooldiv {
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border: 1px solid gold;
}
.mybaddiv {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="myuncoolparentdiv">
    <div class="mybaddiv">
        My Bad Div has width: 100%;
    </div>
    <h2>Other Content</h2>
</div>

<div class="myuncoolparentdiv">
    <div class="mycooldiv">
        My Cool Div has no defined width (~ width: auto;)
    </div>
    <h2>Other Content</h2>
</div>

<div class="myuncoolparentdiv">
    <input class="mybadinput" type="text" value="My Bad Input has width: auto;" />
    <h2>Other Content</h2>
</div>

<div class="myuncoolparentdiv">
    <input class="mybadinputtoo" type="text" value="My Bad Input has width: 100%;" />
    <h2>Other Content</h2>
</div>

<div class="myuncoolparentdiv">
    <input class="myreluctantinput" type="text" value="My Reluctant Input has position: absolute;" />
    <h2>Other Content</h2>
</div>

<div class="myuncoolparentdiv">
    <div class="mycoolparentdiv">
        <input class="mycoolinput" type="text" value="My Cool Input has width: 100% and a cool parent div" />
    </div>
    <h2>Other Content</h2>
</div>
```